# Input shows blank instead of zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a C#.NET MVC4 application. It has an entity with a decimal property (somewhere within a connected MSSQL database):

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:.}")]
public decimal Fines { get; set; }
```

and then I display it as

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fines)
```

If I save it with value 1, 2, 3, ... and then open the record for editing, the text input value is set to the saved value and everything works fine.
However if the value was 0, (it is stored to the database, but) it does not show as "0" string in text box but instead as an empty string "", which causes validation errors since this is a required field (and 0 is a valid value).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format string is a bit weird.. I'm not sure what format you are going for there. Try this:

```
DataFormatString = "{0}"
```

Or if you want it formatted as currency,

```
DataFormatString = "{0:C}"
```

Note: Just tested this:

```
string.Format("{0:.}", (decimal)0)
```

It returns an empty string.

See the msdn pages on [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) numeric format strings.

Comment: This causes the currency sign and a decimal "," to be present in the text box which in turn causes validation error message to appear since the value is no longer a pure number with "." as a decimal mark.
Since it does however solve the empty string problem, it made me think to replace `{0:C}` with `{0:N0}` since the value will always be a natural number anyways and this also does not cause validation problems headache.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - a format of all optional `{#.##}` will also render blank if the value is exactly zero.

Comment: one way to force it to show 0.00 with `DataFormatString = "{0:#.##}"` and value = 0 is use `DataFormatString = "{0:F2}")`